# Where clause on left join subquery is not recognized

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I want to make subquery on left join but the where clause inside the left join is not recognized
Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM proposal p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id_verifikasi), id_proposal FROM verifikasi v WHERE v.id_proposal = p.id_proposal) as v on p.id_proposal = v.id_proposal
WHERE p.id_unit = 6
```

And return an error like this

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'p.id_proposal' in 'where clause'
```

What did I do wrong? And what is the right query

Comment: Subquery can not see the tables of from clause.

Comment: That is why I have written it @a_horse_with_no_name . I can use lateral join but not in mariadb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want to join the table `proposal` to a query that returns the max `id_verifikasi` for each `id_proposal` of the table `verifikasi`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM proposal p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id_proposal, MAX(id_verifikasi) id_verifikasi 
  FROM verifikasi 
  GROUP BY id_proposal
) v ON p.id_proposal = v.id_proposal
WHERE p.id_unit = 6
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for, can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: @AnangHariyantoN The condition: `WHERE v.id_proposal = p.id_proposal` inside the subquery makes the subquery correlated and you can't join a correlated subquery. What you should do is join to the table a subquery that aggregates in the table verifikasi to get all the max id_verifikasi values for each id_proposal.

Comment: @AnangHariyantoN and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You have a correlated subquery in the `FROM` clause.  Only the more recent versions of MySQL support this, via *lateral joins*.

In your case, your query is returning one column and at most one row, so it is a *scalar correlated subquery*.  Because you are filtering in the outer query, the best performing query would use the correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT MAX(v.id_verifikasi)
        FROM verifikasi v
        WHERE v.id_proposal = p.id_proposal
       )
FROM proposal p
WHERE p.id_unit = 6;
```